# How do I do a inner query in ElasticSearch with an outer 'Sort'

Tags: elasticsearch

I'd like to achieve the following in ElasticSearch. I can mostly get the correct results, the problem is that I can't get the ordering of the final results list.

```
SELECT User, ScanDate, TotalSize FROM 
    [SELECT User, ScanDate, TotalSize FROM ElasticSearch 
        GROUP BY User ORDER BY ScanDate]
ORDER BY TotalSize LIMIT 10
```

Essentially, what I'm trying to do is to:

- Get the Top 10 Users based on the TotalSize from their most recent Scan.

I can get the data (using aggregates and sub aggregates of Max). But, I'm then struggling to get the final ordering - and otherwise I'd have to do this the code that consumes this data, which I'd really not have to do.

---

Given the data:

- Rich

  - ScanDate:1, TotalSize:27
  - ScanDate:2, TotalSize:3
  - ScanDate:3, TotalSize:9
- Steve

  - ScanDate:2, TotalSize:2
  - ScanDate:5, TotalSize:1
- John

  - ScanDate:1, TotalSize:50

I want an ordered result of:

1. John (ScanDate:1, TotalSize:50)
2. Rich (ScanDate:3, TotalSize:9)
3. Steve (ScanDate:5, TotalSize:1)

---

The events that are submitted to ElasticSearch look like this:

```
{"User":"Rich","ScanDate":1,"TotalSize":27,"Type":"ScanEvent"}
```

TotalSize is a LONG.
ScanDate is actually a timestamp.
User is a STRING (NOT_ANALYZED).

Comment: what are the indices/types mappings? Is it a "scan" type which contains user, scandate and totalsize?

Comment: I've updated the question. Hope this is sufficient extra info for you to give me a solution :-).

Answer (score 0):

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-sorting.html

I guess this might help in what you are looking..